# Neo4J: "Database in use: false" after loading dump + migrate

Tags: neo4j

I'm running a Neo4J 5.3.0 community edition and tried to load the dump from https://github.com/neo4j-graph-examples/twitch. I managed to load the dump and migrate the database.

My question: **how do I use the "twitch" database?**

```
cosh@osmingestor:~$ sudo neo4j-admin database info
Database name:                neo4j
Database in use:              true
Last committed transaction id:-1
Store needs recovery:         true

Database name:                system
Database in use:              true
Last committed transaction id:-1
Store needs recovery:         true

Database name:                twitch
Database in use:              false
Store format version:         record-aligned-1.1
Store format introduced in:   5.0.0
Last committed transaction id:62742
Store needs recovery:         false
```

show databases doesn't show it for my user "neo4j":

```
neo4j@neo4j> show databases;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| name     | type       | aliases | access       | address          | role      | writer | requestedStatus | currentStatus | statusMessage | default | home  | constituents |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "neo4j"  | "standard" | []      | "read-write" | "localhost:7687" | "primary" | TRUE   | "online"        | "online"      | ""            | TRUE    | TRUE  | []           |
| "system" | "system"   | []      | "read-write" | "localhost:7687" | "primary" | TRUE   | "online"        | "online"      | ""            | FALSE   | FALSE | []           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried to grant access to the database by executing:

```
neo4j@neo4j> grant all database PRIVILEGES ON DATABASES * TO neo4j;
Unsupported administration command: grant all database PRIVILEGES ON DATABASES * TO neo4j
```

Adding "neo4j" as the default admin did not help as well (was working though):

```
neo4j-admin dbms set-default-admin neo4j
```

Comment: What are the "exact" steps (including commands) you did to download and load the dump data? Thnks

Comment: 1. Downloading the dump file
2. sudo neo4j-admin database load twitch --from-path=/home/cosh/neocsv/ 
3. sudo neo4j-admin database migrate twitch --force-btree-indexes-to-range

Comment: thanks. How did you download the dump file?

Comment: Have you created a database -> `CREATE DATABASE twitch;` ?

Comment: I downloaded the data using the browser. there is no issue with that.

Comment: neo4j@neo4j> CREATE DATABASE twitch;
Unsupported administration command: CREATE DATABASE twitch